# Piping between processes in C

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to understand piping in C. I have constructed two test programs that should be working but while running ,the second one prints uninitialized chars rather than the expected string. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

```
int main() 
{
    int parentToChild[2]; //1 Write
    int childToParent[2]; //0 Read
    pipe(parentToChild);
    pipe(childToParent);
    int parent = fork();    
    if(!parent)
    {
        close(parentToChild[1]);
        close(childToParent[0]);
        dup2(1,childToParent[1]); //sets child's stdout to send to parent
        dup2(0,parentToChild[0]); //sets child's stdin to come from parent
        execl("./program","./program",NULL);
    }    
    close(childToParent[1]);
    close(parentToChild[0]);
    FILE* readin = fdopen(childToParent[0],"r");
    FILE* writeto = fdopen(parentToChild[1],"w");
    fprintf(writeto,"msg\n");
    fflush(writeto);
    return 0;
}      
int main()
{        //The child process
    fprintf(stderr,"Program started\n");
    char buff[1024];
    fgets(buff,1024,stdin);
    fprintf(stderr,"%s",buff);
}
```

Comment: Why is there no error checking? Did you try checking for errors?

Comment: check your `dup2()` calls. are the args the right way around?

Comment: I have checked these. This is sample code with error checks and useless prints left out. The system calls are definitely not failing.

Edit: Dup2 sets the first arg to replace the second... I read the man page and interpreted it the other way around. Probably solved.

Comment: Your `dup2()` calls seem to be flipped, `dup2(1,childToParent[1])` sets `childToParent[1]` to be the same as FD `1`. Also, having an `exit()` call after an `exec` is usually a good idea.

Comment: Please add the relevant OS tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the lines:

```
            dup2(1,childToParent[1]); // Error!
            dup2(0,parentToChild[0]); // Error!
```

The order of the file descriptors in the dup2 call is switched. To fix you code you have to change these lines by:

```
            dup2(childToParent[1],1); //sets child's stdout to send to parent
            dup2(parentToChild[0],0); //sets child's stdin to come from parent
```

The dup2(new_fd, old_fd) makes the *newe fd* to be a copy of the *old fd* argument. For more info just check the man page of the dup2.

**Note**: I tested your code by introducing the changes above and now it's working correctly.